# Appending to array using pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to scrape data from soccerway.com and checking whether the page is a completed game/game to be played with each instance being written to a seperate csv file. I am running through 10,000 pages and so have written it using Pools. However, I am getting empty lists from the append function and cannot write anything to the csv files.

I tried writing straight to the file instead of list appending however this gave incomplete files

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import numpy as np
import uuid
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import sys, os

fixturesA = []
linksA = []
statsA = []

def parse(url):
    try:
        #print(url)
        delays = [0.25,0.5,0.75,1]
        delay = np.random.choice(delays)
        #time.sleep(delay)
        #r = requests.get(url)
        r = requests.get(url, timeout = 10)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
        teams = soup.findAll('h3', attrs = {'class' : 'thick'})
        homeTeam = teams[0].text.strip()
        awayTeam = teams[2].text.strip()
        middle = teams[1].text.strip()
        dds = soup.findAll('dd')
        date = dds[1].text.strip()
        gameWeek = dds[2].text.strip()
        if ':' not in middle:
            middle = middle.split(" - ")
            homeGoals = 0
            awayGoals = 0
            homeGoals = middle[0]
            try:
                awayGoals = middle[1]
            except Exception as e:
                homeGoals = "-1"
                awayGoals = "-1"
            matchGoals = int(homeGoals) + int(awayGoals)
            if(matchGoals >= 0):
                if(int(homeGoals) > 0 and int(awayGoals) > 0):
                    btts = "y"
                else:
                    btts = "n"
                halfTimeScore = dds[4].text.strip().split(" - ")
                firstHalfHomeGoals = halfTimeScore[0]
                firstHalfAwayConc = halfTimeScore[0]
                firstHalfAwayGoals = halfTimeScore[1]
                firstHalfHomeConc = halfTimeScore[1]
                firstHalfTotalGoals = int(firstHalfHomeGoals) + int(firstHalfAwayGoals)
                secondHalfHomeGoals = int(homeGoals) - int(firstHalfHomeGoals)
                secondHalfAwayConc = int(homeGoals) - int(firstHalfHomeGoals)
                secondHalfAwayGoals = int(awayGoals) - int(firstHalfAwayGoals)
                secondHalfHomeConc = int(awayGoals) - int(firstHalfAwayGoals)
                secondHalfTotalGoals = matchGoals - firstHalfTotalGoals

                homeTeamContainers = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class' : 'container left'})
                homeTeamStarting = homeTeamContainers[2]
                homeTeamBench = homeTeamContainers[3]
                homeTeamYellows = len(homeTeamStarting.findAll('img', attrs = {'src' : 'https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/700/img/events/YC.png' })) + len(homeTeamBench.findAll('img', attrs = {'src' : 'https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/699/img/events/YC.png' }))
                homeTeamReds = len(homeTeamStarting.findAll('img', attrs = {'src' : 'https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/700/img/events/RC.png' })) + len(homeTeamBench.findAll('img', attrs = {'src' : 'https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/699/img/events/RC.png' }))
                homeTeamCards = homeTeamYellows + homeTeamReds

                awayTeamContainers = soup.findAll('div', attrs = {'class' : 'container right'})
                awayTeamStarting = awayTeamContainers[2]
                awayTeamBench = awayTeamContainers[3]
               awayTeamYellows = len(awayTeamStarting.findAll('img', attrs = {'src' : 'https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/700/img/events/YC.png' })) + len(awayTeamBench.findAll('img', attrs = {'src' : 'https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/699/img/events/YC.png' }))
                awayTeamReds = len(awayTeamStarting.findAll('img', attrs = {'src' : 'https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/700/img/events/RC.png' })) + len(awayTeamBench.findAll('img', attrs = {'src' : 'https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/699/img/events/RC.png' }))
                awayTeamCards = awayTeamYellows + awayTeamReds

                matchCards = homeTeamCards + awayTeamCards
                try:
                    iframe = soup.findAll('iframe')
                    iframeSrc = iframe[1]['src']
                    url = 'https://us.soccerway.com/' + iframeSrc
                    c = requests.get(url,timeout = 10)
                    soupC = BeautifulSoup(c.content, "html.parser")

                    cornerContainer = soupC.findAll('td', attrs = {'class' : 'legend left value'})
                    homeCorners = cornerContainer[0].text.strip()
                    awayCornersConc = homeCorners
                    cornerContainer = soupC.findAll('td', attrs = {'class' : 'legend right value'})
                    awayCorners = cornerContainer[0].text.strip()
                    homeCornersConc = awayCorners
                    matchCorners = int(homeCorners) + int(awayCorners)

                    print("Got Score . " + homeTeam + " vs " + awayTeam+" . " + gameWeek )
                    statsA.append(homeTeam + "," + awayTeam  + "," + gameWeek + "," + homeGoals + "," + awayGoals + "," + str(matchGoals) + "," + btts + "," + firstHalfHomeGoals + "," + firstHalfHomeConc + "," + firstHalfAwayGoals + "," + firstHalfAwayConc + "," + str(firstHalfTotalGoals) + "," + str(secondHalfHomeGoals) + "," + str(secondHalfHomeConc) + "," + str(secondHalfAwayGoals) + "," + str(secondHalfAwayConc) + "," + str(secondHalfTotalGoals) + "," + str(homeTeamCards) + "," + str(awayTeamCards) + "," + str(matchCards) + "," + homeCorners + "," + awayCorners + "," + homeCornersConc + "," + awayCornersConc + "," + str(matchCorners)+","+dds[0].text.strip() + "\n")
                    return None
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Got Score no corners. " + homeTeam + " vs " + awayTeam+" . " + gameWeek + " NO FRAME")
                    statsA.append(homeTeam + "," + awayTeam  + "," + gameWeek + "," + homeGoals + "," + awayGoals + "," + str(matchGoals) + "," + btts + "," + firstHalfHomeGoals + "," + firstHalfHomeConc + "," + firstHalfAwayGoals + "," + firstHalfAwayConc + "," + str(firstHalfTotalGoals) + "," + str(secondHalfHomeGoals) + "," + str(secondHalfHomeConc) + "," + str(secondHalfAwayGoals) + "," + str(secondHalfAwayConc) + "," + str(secondHalfTotalGoals) + "," + str(homeTeamCards) + "," + str(awayTeamCards) + "," + str(matchCards) + "," + "" + "," + "" + "," + "" + "," + "" + "," + ""+","+dds[0].text.strip() + "\n")
                    return None
        else:
            fixturesA.append(homeTeam + "," + awayTeam  + "," + gameWeek + "," + date + "\n")
            linksA.append(url + "\n")
            print(homeTeam + " vs " + awayTeam + " at " + middle + " GW:" + gameWeek)
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
        linksA.append(url + "\n")
        print(url)
        return None


stats = open('Statsv2.csv','a',encoding='utf-8')
fixtures = open('fixturesv2.csv','w',encoding='utf-8')

with open('links.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]

links = open('links.txt','w')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    p = Pool(20)  # Pool tells how many at a time
    records = p.map(parse, content)
    p.terminate()
    p.join()

    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running Windows? Then the answer is that multi-processing in Windows creates copies instead of forks. So you have your main process with the lists and you get your working processes (from pool) with their own separate set of lists.

The workers most likely fill their list correctly, but the lists in the main-process don't get any data and so are staying empty. And the workers do not return anything. So, as you write your files in the main-process, you get empty files.

An easy way to solve this is creating pipes or queues between the main process and the workers to allow communication between the threads. You could also use shared arrays like they are provided by the multiprocessing class, but than you would need to know the length during creation.

see documentation: [Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Comment: note that this would also apply under fork based system (e.g. Linux/OSX) as well, variables in children will be copies so modifying them won't change the value in the parent process

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought that forking would create some shared variables. Now I know better.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by @RaJa you're not actually doing anything the parent/controlling process can see.  the easiest is just to return values from the `map`ped function

for example, `parse()` could return tuple at the end like:

```
def parse(url):
  # do work
  return url, homeTeam, awayTeam, gameWeek, homeGoals, awayGoals # ...
```

then the parent process can receive the values and do useful things like saving them to a CSV file:

```
import csv

with Pool(20) as pool:
  records = pool.map(parse, content)

with open('stats.csv', 'w') as fd:
  out = csv.writer(fd)
  out.writerow([
    'url', 'hometeam', 'awayteam',
    # and the remaining column names for the header
  ])
  out.writerows(records)
```